# When triggering to check all checkboxes, how do you prevent other checkboxes from being checked on other pages inside dataTables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

Since I used dataTables and put it inside a `<form>` to pass data to the server, I discovered that I cannot pass all the data inside per page, cause other elements `<td>` are hidden so in able to send it all to the database I need to sort them depending on `show entities` 10 - 100. But what I want to do is this. If I click the checkbox I made to select all checkboxes on that particular page, it should not select the other checkboxes from other pages. How should I do that? Any ideas? Thanks you in advance for the help.

Here is the code example

```js
//Selecting all checkboxes that are not disabled
$("#select_all").on('click', function() {
  $('#dataTables').DataTable()
    .column(3)
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
});

// Sorting of column in dataTables
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTables").DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" integrity="sha512-ARJR74swou2y0Q2V9k0GbzQ/5vJ2RBSoCWokg4zkfM29Fb3vZEQyv0iWBMW/yvKgyHSR/7D64pFMmU8nYmbRkg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-yDlE7vpGDP7o2eftkCiPZ+yuUyEcaBwoJoIhdXv71KZWugFqEphIS3PU60lEkFaz8RxaVsMpSvQxMBaKVwA5xg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Sample
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-heading -->
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table width="100%" id="dataTables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>
                  <center>
                    Select
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
                  </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

- remove the duplicate ID from the other checkboxes. ID needs to be unique
- only check visible checkboxes

---

```
$('#dataTables')
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled:visible')
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
```

```js
//Selecting all checkboxes that are not disabled
$("#select_all").on('click', function() {
  $('#dataTables')
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled:visible')
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
});

// Sorting of column in dataTables
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataTables").DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" integrity="sha512-ARJR74swou2y0Q2V9k0GbzQ/5vJ2RBSoCWokg4zkfM29Fb3vZEQyv0iWBMW/yvKgyHSR/7D64pFMmU8nYmbRkg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-yDlE7vpGDP7o2eftkCiPZ+yuUyEcaBwoJoIhdXv71KZWugFqEphIS3PU60lEkFaz8RxaVsMpSvQxMBaKVwA5xg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Sample
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-heading -->
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table width="100%" id="dataTables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>
                  <center>
                    Select
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
                  </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks sir for answering! reminded me to use one ID, I replaced my code with your code :) . However it still does not meet the answer to my question regarding on how will I make or prevent other checkboxes from other pages inside my dataTable to be checked. My goal is the checkboxes for every column per page can be selected all and not all other checkboxes from other page. For me to pass to my server side. I am still new in dataTables. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try my code with more than one page? I believe it will not check checkboxes that are not yet visible on the page

Comment: Hi sorry! I forgot to delete the other two excess code of mine, I did not notice, my fault. It worked now :) , I'll accept this as an answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi sir, I have additional question. How can I prevent the select-all checkbox of mine from still being `:checked` in other pages? . for example is when I selected all checkboxes for every column per page it worked but when I click other pages it is still `:checked` . Thank you again

Comment: Uncheck it in the pagination